# First cell is hidden when displaying the WKInterfaceTable

Tags: apple-watch, wkinterfacetable

I have a WKInterfaceTable that starts hidden (as it is retrieving information from the server in my original code) and when the table is filled I just display it and the first row start collapsed.

[image]

Here you have the willActivate code.

```
- (void)willActivate {
// This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
[super willActivate];
[self.myTable setNumberOfRows:10 withRowType:@"MyCell"];
for (int i = 0; i < self.myTable.numberOfRows; i++) {
    MyCell * cell = [self.myTable rowControllerAtIndex:i];
    [cell.myTitle setText:@"My title"];
}

[self.myTable setHidden:NO];

}
```

**UPDATE** I discovered that if I fill the table on a block sent to the main queue it solves the problem.

```
- (void)willActivate {
// This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
[super willActivate];
[self.myTable setHidden:NO];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    [self.myTable setNumberOfRows:10 withRowType:@"MyCell"];
    for (int i = 0; i < self.myTable.numberOfRows; i++) {
        MyCell * cell = [self.myTable rowControllerAtIndex:i];
        [cell.myTitle setText:@"My title"];
    }

});


}
```